# Url to get google registation code for app

Tags: c#, android, google-app-engine, xamarin

I have a piece of code which apparently I got from another site's google key.
So the code works, however can figure out which url to use to get the key?
To be clear I am looking for the url which should be in the place of "googleApiUrl".

Its the key which google provide when a new app is installed:

```
var googleOk = new WebClient ().DownloadString (googleApiUrl).Trim().Equals("1");
            lock (locker)
            {
                if( String.IsNullOrEmpty( LocalSettings.Instance.CurrentUserUDID ) )
                {
                    var instanceID = InstanceID.GetInstance (this);
                    var _token = instanceID.GetToken (
                        Constants.PushNotifications_SERVER_ID, GoogleCloudMessaging.InstanceIdScope, null);
                    var token = "";
                    if(googleOk){
                        token = instanceID.GetToken ( Constants.PushNotifications_SERVER_ID, GoogleCloudMessaging.InstanceIdScope, null);
                    }
                    if(OnReceivedUDID!=null)
                    {
                        OnReceivedUDID(this, new EventArgs());
                    }
                    SaveRegistrationToLocalSettings (token);
                }
                else
                {
                    if(OnReceivedUDID!=null)
                    {
                        OnReceivedUDID(this, new EventArgs());
                    }
                }
            }
```

Can somebody provide this?

Comment: try this https://gcm-http.googleapis.com:443/gcm/send

Comment: Nope, does not work...